# Chess knight move simulator

Tags: java, beginner, interview-questions

I was asked to write chess simulation of pieces as a take home interview question and was given [this spec](https://pastebin.com/VbgWA5SK).

This is what I came up with:

#### ChessGenerator.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ChessGenerator {
    private static final int n = 8;
    private static final int m = 8;
    private static final int[][] board = new int[8][8];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String piece = args[0];
        String position = args[1];

        Point point = PositionTransformer.translateToPoint(position);
        run(piece, position, point);
    }

    public static List<Point> run(String piece, String position, Point point) {
        List<Point> result = null;
        if(piece.equals("Horse")) {
            result = new Horse().findAllPossibleMoves(board, point.getX(), point.getY());
            System.out.println(result.toString());

        }
        return result;
    }

    // TODO Remove
    public String letterPosition(String position) {
        return position.replaceAll("[0-9]","");
    }

    // TODO Remove
    public String numericPosition(String position) {
        return position.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]","");
    }
}
```

#### Horse.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Horse extends Piece {

    public List<Point> findAllPossibleMoves(int mat[][], int p, int q) {
        List<Point> result = new ArrayList<Point>();

        int X[] = {2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2};
        int Y[] = {1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1};

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            int x = p + X[i];
            int y = q + Y[i];

            if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < n && y < m
                    && mat[x][y] == 0)
                result.add(new Point(x, y));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

#### Piece.java

```
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Piece {
    public static final int n = 8;
    public static final int m = 8;

    public abstract List<Point> findAllPossibleMoves(int board[][], int m, int n);
}
```

#### Point.java

```
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point{" +
                "x=" + x +
                ", y=" + y +
                '}';
    }
}
```

#### PositionTransformer.java

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PositionTransformer {
    private static final Map<String, Point> transformer = new HashMap<String, Point>() {{
        put("A1", new Point(7,0));
        put("A2", new Point(6,0));
        put("A3", new Point(5,0));
        put("A4", new Point(4,0));
        put("A5", new Point(3,0));
        put("A6", new Point(2,0));
        put("A7", new Point(1,0));
        put("A8", new Point(0,0));
        put("B1", new Point(7,1));
        put("B2", new Point(6,1));
        put("B3", new Point(5,1));
        put("B4", new Point(4,1));
        put("B5", new Point(3,1));
        put("B6", new Point(2,1));
        put("B7", new Point(1,1));
        put("B8", new Point(0,1));
        put("C1", new Point(7,2));
        put("C2", new Point(6,2));
        put("C3", new Point(5,2));
        put("C4", new Point(4,2));
        put("C5", new Point(3,2));
        put("C6", new Point(2,2));
        put("C7", new Point(1,2));
        put("C8", new Point(0,2));
        put("D1", new Point(7,3));
        put("D2", new Point(6,3));
        put("D3", new Point(5,3));
        put("D4", new Point(4,3));
        put("D5", new Point(3,3)); 
        put("D6", new Point(2,3));
        put("D7", new Point(1,3));
        put("D8", new Point(0,3));
        put("E1", new Point(7,4));
        put("E2", new Point(6,4));
        put("E3", new Point(5,4));
        put("E4", new Point(4,4));
        put("E5", new Point(3,4));
        put("E6", new Point(2,4));
        put("E7", new Point(1,4));
        put("E8", new Point(0,4));
        put("F1", new Point(7,5));
        put("F2", new Point(6,5));
        put("F3", new Point(5,5));
        put("F4", new Point(4,5));
        put("F5", new Point(3,5));
        put("F6", new Point(2,5));
        put("F7", new Point(1,5));
        put("F8", new Point(0, 5));
        put("G1", new Point(7,6));
        put("G2", new Point(6,6));
        put("G3", new Point(5,6));
        put("G4", new Point(4,6));
        put("G5", new Point(3,6));
        put("G6", new Point(2,6));
        put("G7", new Point(1,6));
        put("G8", new Point(0, 6));
        put("H1", new Point(7,7));
        put("H2", new Point(6,7));
        put("H3", new Point(5,7));
        put("H4", new Point(4,7));
        put("H5", new Point(3,7));
        put("H6", new Point(2,7));
        put("H7", new Point(1,7));
        put("H8", new Point(0, 7));
    }};

    public static Point translateToPoint(String position) {
        return transformer.get(position);
    }

    public static Map<String, Point> unmodifiableMap() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(transformer);
    }
}
```

#### This is the feedback I received

Variables names must be self-explanatory.
Unused variables.
Hardcoded PositionTransformer. Could have written a logic for that.
Implemented only 1 piece i.e. Horse.

I agree with unused variables and due to time constraint only implemented horse piece. Not sure what is meant by `PositionTransformer` review comment. How else could the code be improved?

Comment: You should adjust the page title to "chess knight move generator" since you only implemented that. As a general chess move generator, your code is off-topic since it doesn't fully implement the spec.

Comment: I think you should add the specs in this post :) Imagine the pastebin was to be deleted, we'd lose context on your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your `PositionTransformer` comment :

We have an 8x8 board where columns are represented by letters and rows by numbers (it might be the opposite I don't really play chess). *But that doesn't matter to your code.* What the code is working with is a 8x8 grid.

However, your user interacts with the board with letters and numbers. What this means is, instead of using a map of strings that maps to points, I believe your code should only be a grid and you should parse what the user gives you in a format you can use with the grid. For example :

Note that I haven't coded in Java in awhile, so I'll be writing Java-like pseudo-code that won't compile, but you'll get my idea.

```
//Create the board
int[][] board = new int[8][8];

private Point getPositionFromUserInput(String cellId) {
    //You expect a format of [A-H][1-8], so let's first check if this makes sense
    if (!Pattern.matches("[A-H][1-8]", cellId)) {
         throw exception regarding bad argument
    }

    //Letters are mapped A=0,..., H=7
    int column = cellId[0] - 'A';

    //Numbers are mapped 1=7,...,8=0
    int row = '1' - cell[1] + 7;

    return new Point(row, column);
}

//Return a Point(0,3)
Point p = getPositionFromUserInput("A5");
```

But **frankly**, I think this is a useless abstraction. Your interviewer didn't agree with my it seems, but a chess board is by definition pretty much hardcoded, so there's no need to take time to write specific logic to deal with changing the chess position to a point, as this would lead to potential bugs that could've been avoided. Anyways, I also think that in an interview question, if you can write **why** you did some things, interviewers might agree with you.

Now, "Variables names must be self-explanatory. Unused variables" is pretty bad. In an interview question, you should give it your all to give a solution that's as close as possible to what you'd do when you work and unused variables is a pretty red flag regarding code quality, as are poor variable names. Even though sometimes poor variable names are inevitable.

Now, there's one other red flag I see in the code that'd make me question myself as an interviewer : Why is there only a setter for the `x` variable of `Point` and not for `y`? I believe you added it and forgot to remove it, but I may be wrong. Anyways, a `Point` should be an immutable structure, it's just easier to manage. Why should a point change location? It's a pretty static thing.

Finally, you use an abstract class to define `Piece`, which I think isn't a bad idea in itself, but in both the `Piece` and `Knight` class you don't use any instance variables/functions, so abstraction seems like a bad idea. Try to answer this question : Why would you use an abstract method `findAllPossibleMoves` when it could be `static` and it wouldn't change a thing?

Maybe what you want isn't a `Knight` class, but a `KnightMoveGenerator` that could implement an interface `MoveGenerator`?

Answer (score 3):

I would implement `Piece` as an `enum`, with an element for each piece.

A `ChessBoard` would have `rows` and `cols` instead of `n` and `m`, where each cell would be a `Piece`.

```
ChessBoard b = new ChessBoard();
b.setPieceAt(0, 0, Piece.ROOK);
b.getPieceAt(0, 0); // Piece.ROOK
```

The `ChessBoard` could, for example, return `Piece.NONE` for empty spaces and `null` for out-of-bounds access. This would save you a lot of bounds-checking during move generation. An implementation trick would be to reserve extra rows and columns in the backing `Piece[][]` array, so that there are 2 empty rows and columns to either side of valid in-the-board positions; this would remove bounds-checking from the `ChessBoard` code too.

A `Position` would be an immutable row-col combination, as in "e4", and would be usable on a board to set and get pieces (but I would still keep check-by-coordinates as seen above for quicker move generation). Positions would know how to parse and write themselves.

Within the `Piece` enum, you could implement parsing and printing (so that, say, a `PAWN` can print itself as a `"Pawn"`). Move generation could use, without exposing them, several helper methods::

```
public List<Position> generateMoves(Position p, ChessBoard b) {
     List<Position> moves = new ArrayList<>();
     switch (this) {
         case PAWN:
            generatePawnMoves(p, b, moves); // private method
            break;
         case QUEEN:
            generateDiagonalMoves(p, b, moves);
            generateHorizontalMoves(p, b, moves);
            break;            
         // ...              
     }
     return moves;
}
```

Since the statement does not require you to implement black and white pieces, I would ignore all those aspects. They can all be added later, and the exercise explicitly requests not over-complicating the answer.

If you look further into move generation, your `Knight` code contains 2 arrays, one of `dx` and another of `dy` displacements. Very similar code could generate `KING` moves (as 8 "jumps", one to each adjacent position), and placing that in a loop that keeps on "jumping" until it hits something would generate Bishop and Rook (and thus Queen) moves. Code reuse is good, because it makes testing your code easier, and gives you shorter code to look at.

Answer (score 1):

First, the spec is crap. It uses the words chess and chessboard but gives them completely unusual meanings. The best thing to do is with such a spec is to reject it and require clear instructions, using the exact same terms that the rest of the world uses as well. Even if refining the spec costs a day of work, this is worth it since later in the implementation changing any small detail will cost 100 days. If you spot something wrong at the very beginning, fix it quickly before you get used to it.

This spec is crap for the following reasons:

- It names the rows A to H. In chess, the rows are called ranks instead, and they are numbered from 1 to 8.
- It names the columns 1 to 8. In chess, the columns are called files instead, and they are numbered from A to H.
- It calls the Knight a Horse. It's called a knight, that's the international standard when talking about chess in English.
- 2 vertical + 1 horizontal step are not 2.5 steps. In the usual drawings of knight moves, it's either \$\sqrt5 \approx 2.236\$ steps for a direct move or \$1+\sqrt2\approx2.414\$ steps for a straight move followed by a diagonal move. To go exactly 2.5 steps, the horse would first have to go 1.25 steps straight, then make a sharp turn towards the target cell, which at that point is exactly 1.25 steps away. What could be the point of requiring exactly 2.5 steps in the spec?
- I hope they meant "on an otherwise empty chessboard" when they wrote "on an empty chessboard". I'll interpret it that way for now.

All these are things you should have noticed when trying to implement the full exercise.

Now to your code:

```java
    private static final int n = 8;
```

This line already reveals that you don't know the Java naming conventions. This is a constant (because of the `static final`), and constants are written in uppercase.

The variable name is complete crap. The name `n` stands for a number. It's obvious from the code that 8 is a number, and it's also obvious that 8 is an integer. Therefore the variable name does not add a single bit of information to the code. In cases like this, just omit the variable name and write the number directly. Or, pick a better name. One that describes the purpose of the variable. This one could be named `FILES` or `RANKS`. The same applies to your other variables, they are equally bad. On the other hand, the method names you chose are good, which means you just need to apply this knowledge to the variable names as well.

```java
new Horse()
```

Why do you create a new horse each time you want to find the possible moves? Your Horse class does not have any fields or other state that it might need to preserve. Therefore, creating a new object each time is a waste of computing time.

```java
        List<Point> result = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

The second `<Point>` is redundant, you can just write `<>` without repeating the type name. Your IDE should have offered to fix this for you. If it didn't, your IDE is not good enough. Get a better one, IntelliJ can do this, and it has over 1000 other inspections that help you write good code. Even Eclipse can fix this for you, and Eclipse is lagging behind almost 10 years in Java features, and 20 years in usability. So there is absolutely no excuse having this redundancy in the code.

As others already said, the `PositionTransformer` looks really boring and unimaginative. You're lucky that a chess board is only 8×8 and not 19×19 like a go board. For comparison, here is some C code that I wrote to transform a string into a square:

```c
static bool
Parse_Square(const char *str, Square *out_square)
{
    const char *files = "ABCDEFGH";
    const char *file = strchr(files, str[0]);
    if (file == NULL)
        return false;

    const char *ranks = "12345678";
    const char *rank = strchr(ranks, str[1]);
    if (rank == NULL)
        return false;

    out_square->file = file - files;
    out_square->rank = rank - ranks;
    return true;
}
```

That is much shorter and it is easily extendible to other board sizes, with minimal effort. Just imagine if you wanted to have lowercase board coordinates instead of uppercase ones. In your code, you had to adjust 64 lines of code. In my code, it would be a single line of code.

```
    private static final Map<String, Point> transformer = new HashMap<>() {{
        put("A1", new Point(7,0));
        put("A2", new Point(6,0));
    }};
```

The double braces `{{ … }}` are an anti-pattern. They needlessly create a class that derives from HashMap, while all you need is a HashMap. In this program, there is no need for inheritance or derived classes.

Your code is not only missing 5 of the 6 chess pieces, it is also lacking unit tests, and this was part of the requirement. You wrote that you didn't have enough time. This may be an excuse for the exam, but not for your post to Code Review. Here you have plenty of time and you should have added the full code and the unit tests.

Comment: Your parsing code is C++, and not plain C. I would not place so much emphasis on the spec being not-really-chess, because implementations can really show quite a lot about how someone programs; being too similar to real chess could lead to copy-pasting of actual chess implementations, of which there are many.

Comment: @tucuxi My parsing code is pure C. Why do you think it could be C++?

Comment: "This may be an excuse for the exam, but not for your post to Code Review" I disagree. The code works fine here and this is a reviewable code unit.

Comment: @RolandIllig today I learnt that the `static` keyword could be used to limit the scope of plain-C functions, and that C99 added a `bool` `#define` to the standard via `stdbool.h`. I stand corrected (and feel old because I still remember declaring my own `#defines`). On the other hand, I still think that OP's spec is not as bad as you make it.

Comment: @tucuxi Yep, the other parts of the spec are fine. But switching the coordinate axes is a real problem in other contexts, and naming the Knight a Horse is also unusual enough that as a software developer you should ask whether these choices have been made intentionally to deviate from well-established standards.